# Eclipse not building WEB-INF/classes for GWT

Tags: eclipse, gwt, maven-2, gwt-platform

I've been using **GWT** together with **Maven**, but whatever I try to do, Eclipse does not want to compile the source code to the usual ***webapp/WEB-INF/classes*** folder automatically. I tried reproducing the problem using the *gwtp-sample-basic* sample from GWT-Platform; which can be found here: 
[gwtp-samples-0.6.zip](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/downloads/detail?name=gwtp-samples-0.6.zip&can=2&q=)

Deploying and running the project via Jetty without the classes results in the following expected errors:

```
[WARN] Could not instantiate listener example.project.server.MyGuiceServletContextListener
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: example.project.server.MyGuiceServletContextListener
...
[WARN] EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter
...
[WARN] failed guiceFilter: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter
...
[WARN] Failed startup of context com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@aec7ab1{/,/home/user/Documents/Workspace/project/src/main/webapp}
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter
...
```

Using Ant, the classes get built to the correct folder *webapp/WEB-INF/classes* but it fails to do so with any Maven configuration I've tried to far.

- Could this be something Maven specific?
- Anything I might have forgotten to configure in Eclipse?
- Anyone that had similar problems, plus found how to fix them?

*Sidenotes: Using the default Sonatype Maven plugin for Eclipse. Also tried using the webAppCreator tool to reinitialize a Maven project but it didn't change the outcome. Using the default run configurations provided. The webapp/WEB-INF/lib automatically contains the required libraries.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven usually compiles into `target/classes`. When you build a WAR with Maven, Maven will copy the classes from there so they end up at the right place in the WAR.

So the question is: What do you mean by "running the project"? Usually, that means building a WAR and deploying it. If you do that, everything should work.

My guess is that you want to avoid this effort because it takes a pretty long time. But unless you tell us specifically how you have set up your project and how you "run" it (which container, which plug-ins do you use, things like that), it's impossible to help.

**[EDIT]** Your main problem is probably how the classpath is handed over to Jetty and whether it honors it or builds its own.

You may want to look at the [GWT Maven Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/gwt-maven-plugin/) which says "integrate nicelly into Eclipse, thanks to M2Eclipse and Google Eclipse plugins."

Also [this blog post](http://googlewebtoolkit.blogspot.com/2010/08/how-to-use-google-plugin-for-eclipse.html) may help you.

Comment: I should have mentioned that running equals deploying and debugging via Jetty; which is the default server when using the GWT plugin for Eclipse.

Comment: @Aaron Follow up question on this: You don't need those WEB-INF/classes for deployment, right, unless you have services? I see every UI class in there too compiled to a .class, but GWT is using the JS, so don't I want to get ride of those files? My project has about 2400 files in that classes folder, and 400 in the actual public folder.

Comment: @JosephLust: No complex questions in comments, please. Post a new question instead.